# Exercise on the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-integration

I have to show without using any derivative that:

$$i) \; \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+i-1}=\int_1^2\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$

And, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$ii) \;\text{If} \; r\in \mathbb{N}, \;\text{then}\; \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i^r}{n^{r+1}}=\frac{1}{r+1}.$$

So, from

$f\in R([a,b])\leftrightarrow$ $f$ is integrable in the sense of Riemann's definition.

We have the next Corollary:

$$\int_a^bf\,d\alpha=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{N(n)}f\left(\xi_i^n\right)\cdot \left(\alpha( x_i^n)- \alpha( x_{i-1}^n)\right)$$

So, I'm trying to follow an example done in class but don't quite get it:

$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n}=\frac{1}{2n}\left( \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2n}{2n}}\right)$$

And since $f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, we get $f\in R\left(\left[0,1 \right]\right)$

Then:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n} \right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}f\left( \frac{k}{2n} \right) \left( \frac{k}{2n}-\frac{k-1}{2n} \right)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+x}\,dx.$$

What kind of $\alpha(x)$ would I need for my particular problem $(i)$?
What does it has to satisfy in order for the last equality to hold?

I guess that understanding $i)$ will make $ii)$ easier, but.. is there something trivial that I'm not seeing?

Comment: You can use normal Riemann integral for your original problem

Answer (score 1):

(1) Let $f:\Bbb R_{>0}\to\Bbb R$ be the function $f(x)=1/x$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac 1{n+0}+
\frac 1{n+1}+\dots+
\frac 1{n+(n-1)}
&=
\frac 1n\left(
 \underbrace{\frac 1{1+ \frac 0n}}_{f\left(1+\frac 0n\right)}
+\underbrace{\frac 1{1+ \frac 1n}}_{f\left(1+\frac 1n\right)}
+\underbrace{\frac 1{1+ \frac {n-1}n}}_{f\left(1+\frac {n-1}n\right)}
\ \right)
&\to\int_1^2 f(x)\; dx\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Above, 
$1+\frac 0n$,
$1+\frac 1n$, $\dots$, 
$1+\frac {n-1}n$,
are intermediate points in the interval $[1,2]$ in the obvious equidistant intervals of length $\frac 1n$, so the Riemann sums above converge to the Riemann integral of $f$ on $[1,2]$.

(2) Use the Rieman sums convergence to the Riemann integral for the function $x\to x^r$, considered on $[0,1]$, so rewrite
$$
\sum_{1\le k\le n} \frac {k^r}{n^{r+1}}
=
\frac 1n\sum_{1\le k\le n} \left(\frac kn\right)^r
\to
\int_0^1x^r\;dx =\frac 1{r+1}\ .
$$